# data is not transfering to thingsboard from nodered via mqtt

Tags: json, node-red, thingsboard

I try to send data to thingsboard via mqtt. The mqtt node shows connected status but data is not transferring to thingsboard. Eventhough data is in json format, data is not receving in thingsboard. Any help will be more helpful.

sample sending data:

```
{    "main-door": "closed",    "main-light": "OFF"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the Thingsboard rules for payload format at https://thingsboard.io/docs/getting-started-guides/helloworld/#pushing-data-using-mqtt-coap-or-http

You did not say which topic you are publishin to.